# How print a loop inside of sweet alert window

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sweetalert

I want to loop an array and show the result using sweet alert, I am new in this so I try the code below, but show me some like [object],[object]

```
swal({
  content:{
    element: "ul",
    attributes: {
      innerHTML:$.each(json.DATA.ARYPUB, function (key, img) {
                      "<li><img src='"+img.PATH+"'></li>"
       })
    }
  }
})
```

Can someone help me, please

Comment: One way could be generating the string outside and then set the complete html string to `innerHTML` property. There is no reason for do it inside. Like: `var html = ""; $.each(json.DATA.ARYPUB, function (key, img) {html += "<li><img src='"+img.PATH+"'></li>"});`

Comment: Thanks so mush can you give a example code I don't know who get done this

Comment: Use `Array.map()` instead: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/nw2L8u7m/ ($.each() returns the array you fed into it)

Comment: could you share the content of `json.DATA.ARYPUB`

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be generating the complete `HTML` outside the constructor of the `alert` and then set that html string to the related property. Example:

```
var html = "";

$.each(json.DATA.ARYPUB, function(key, img)
{
    html += "<li><img src='" + img.PATH + "'></li>"
});

swal({
    content:{
        element: "ul",
        attributes: {
            innerHTML: html
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue so, I did this

```
const addOption = (arr) => {
  let optionItems;
  arr.forEach(item =>{

    optionItems += `<option value="${item}">${item}</option>`
  })
  return optionItems
}

//in swal 

 Swal.fire({
    html:addOption(Yourarray) 
    })
```